No matching configuration of project :unityLibrary was found
I’m trying to import my Unity project into my Flutter app as a widget. Here are the steps I followed:

Exported Unity Project: I exported the Unity project inside the android folder of my Flutter app.

Included in Android Level build.gradle:
include ":unityLibrary"
include ":app"

project(":unityLibrary").projectDir = new File("../unity/unityLibrary")


Added Dependency in App Level build.gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}



However, I'm encountering the following error while building the app:
Error Message:

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve project :unityLibrary.
Required by:
project :app
> No matching configuration of project :unityLibrary was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
- None of the consumable configurations have attributes.*

Additional Information:

SDK Version: 34
Unity Version: 2022.3
Gradle Version:1.7.10

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
I already tried

Double-checking the paths to ensure they are correct.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Updating dependencies.
added debug build type in unity

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        }
    }


:unityLibrary does not have a build-type debug.

already added it to unityLibrary build.gradle but still same error is coming

You sure there's a ../unity/unityLibrary/build.gradle? One can also find that on the Unity forum, with about the same logical conclusion: https://discussions.unity.com/t/unity-as-a-library-no-matching-configuration-of-project-unitylibrary-was-found/937237

First of all update path like below:
include ":app"


include ":unityLibrary"
project(":unityLibrary").projectDir = file("./unityLibrary")

and then move it to settings.gradle file
